# Chrome auto tab discarding disable java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, google-chrome

Chrome implement new feature which is called auto tab discarding through this feature enable user when user not on the tab that tab will discard and when user re click on that tab chrome auto refresh that tab. here is the link of [Article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding). this is is very good feature But my problem is I'm showing notification when our tab is active in chrome but because of this feature our Tab is discard and not able to show notifications anymore.

**My Question is** :- How to Disable this feature or there is any way to keep my tab active or any way to prevent that from discarding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users can switch off automatic tab discarding by setting the respective flag in Chrome using this link: chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding

But every page with states depending on user input do have the same problem like yours. Usually, you can prevent unloading a page with handling the onbeforeunload event in JavaScript. Unfortunately, Google does not prevent a solution for this on all systems, despite many users had problems with this feature already in the experimental phase, as you can read in the user comments:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding

For ChomeOS, the problem seams to be fixed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123049

On Android, automatic tab discarding is quite aggressive and prevents using Chrome for applications with significant user input, imho.

On Windows, automatic tab discarding only starts if the available memory is low.

Sorry for not coming up with a proper solution here (I'd be really happy to have one) - I did extensive research and this is all I could find.

Comment: I think `beforeunload` would not get fired on tab discard, since the discarded tab would only be frozen, not truly unloaded. However, I haven't made any experiments, and wouldn't know if it actually got fired for some reason.